# Eliminate duplicates in Join over 3 Tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, outer-join

I'm using the following select statement to populate a grid on my website with listings that have been entered into 3 tables.

```
BND_Listing = Main Data
BND_ListingCategories = My Category data for the Listing Table
BND_LingingJunction = Junction Table for multi-category listings.
```

I've just implemented the Junction table as any listing can have more than 1 Category but my problem arrises when I have (ListingX that is using CategoryY & CategoryZ) will show up on my listing twice for CatX & CatY that's because there are 2 entries for this particular listing on my junction table so I understand why it's showing up twice but I'd like everything to show up just once rather than once per each category.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM BND_ListingJunction 
    JOIN BND_listing on BND_listing.LID = BND_ListingJunction.Junc_LID
    JOIN BND_ListingCategories 
       on BND_ListingCategories.CatID = 
            BND_ListingJunction.Junc_CatID
WHERE (CategoryName = '[querystring:filter-Category]' or
          '[querystring:filter-Category]'='All')
    and (City = '[querystring:filter-City]' or 
          '[querystring:filter-City]'='All')
    and (Region= '[querystring:filter-State]' or 
          '[querystring:filter-State]'='All')
    and (Country= '[querystring:filter-Country]' or 
          '[querystring:filter-Country]'='All')
    and isnull(Company,'') <> ''
ORDER by Company ASC
```

I realize that using distinct is not working here because it's 1st pulling from my junction table perhaps the query needs be be organized differently?

Comment: Because distinct is applied to every output column from the query.

Comment: @CharlesBretana so does that mean I apply distinct to my JOINS's also?

Comment: No, see my edited answer. Distinct is applied to the final output of the entire query. If, considering the entire output (all the columns), there are any rows which are the same (all the column values are identical) then the extra duplicates are eliminated.  Your query selected everything from all the tables in the query, so since the category values are different for each category, those rows are different and are not eliminated. You need to limit the output to only the columns from the Listing table. You could explicitly list the columns you want, or use a subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because distinct is applied to every output column from the query.
What table are `City`, `Region`, `Country` and `Company` in ? If they are in `ListingJunction' or`ListingCategories`, 
If you need distinct list of Listings and Categories,

```
SELECT DISTINCT l.*, c.CategoryName 
FROM BND_Listing l
   Join BND_ListingJunction j
      on j.Junc_LID = l.LID
   join BND_ListingCategories c
      on c.CatId = j.Junc_CatID
Where (c.CategoryName = '[querystring:filter-Category]' or
                    '[querystring:filter-Category]'='All')
      and (City = '[querystring:filter-City]' or 
                    '[querystring:filter-City]'='All')
      and (Region= '[querystring:filter-State]' or 
                    '[querystring:filter-State]'='All')
      and (Country= '[querystring:filter-Country]' or 
                    '[querystring:filter-Country]'='All')
      and isnull(Company,'') <> ''
Order by l.Company, l.LID
```

If all you want is distinct list of Listings try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM BND_Listing l 
Where Exists
  (Select * from BND_ListingJunction j
      join BND_ListingCategories c
          on c.CatId = j.Junc_CatID
   Where j.Junc_LID = l.LID
      and (c.CategoryName = '[querystring:filter-Category]' or
                    '[querystring:filter-Category]'='All')
      and (City = '[querystring:filter-City]' or 
                    '[querystring:filter-City]'='All')
      and (Region= '[querystring:filter-State]' or 
                    '[querystring:filter-State]'='All')
      and (Country= '[querystring:filter-Country]' or 
                    '[querystring:filter-Country]'='All')
      and isnull(Company,'') <> '')
ORDER by l.Company ASC
```

If they are in `BND_Listing', try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM BND_Listing l 
Where Exists
      (Select * from BND_ListingJunction j
         join BND_ListingCategories c
             on c.CatId = j.Junc_CatID
       Where j.Junc_LID = l.LID
           and (c.CategoryName = '[querystring:filter-Category]' or
                    '[querystring:filter-Category]'='All'))
   and (l.City = '[querystring:filter-City]' or 
                    '[querystring:filter-City]'='All')
   and (l.Region= '[querystring:filter-State]' or 
                    '[querystring:filter-State]'='All')
   and (l.Country= '[querystring:filter-Country]' or 
                    '[querystring:filter-Country]'='All')
   and isnull(l.Company,'') <> ''
ORDER by l.Company ASC
```

Comment: thank you for this it does work however my category names are not pulling in. I have a field called "CategoryName" in my BND_ListingCategories table that is not showing.

Comment: then you need to add category name to the output

Comment: Would I do that with a UNION?

Comment: City, State, Country are in the Listing table & CategoryName is in the Category table. Junction Table only has CatID,LID

Comment: Perhaps I should add CategoryName to the Junction Table?

Comment: You don't need to do that, you just need to explicitly list the columns you want to be in the output. These will be the only columns that the `distinct` keyword will operate on.

Comment: If I do `SELECT DISTINCT Company,CategoryName,City,State` it says CategoryName not a valid column. Using your 2nd example

Comment: I apologize for the repeated questions, I'm new to TSQL. I appreciate your help!

Comment: well what is the column name for the column that has the Category Name in it?

Comment: CategoryName it's in the BND_ListingCategories Table

Comment: Then the first SQL statement in my answer should work

Comment: I tried that one it does duplicate every listing in my BND_Listing depending on how many times it's referenced by category in the Junction Table.

Basically, I'd like to just display every unique record from BND_Listing just once even if it's referenced multiple times in the Junction Table.

Comment: Please read my answer.  You can't do that if you elect to include the category name. If there's more than one category for a Listing, how is the computer supposed to decide which category name to include?  The only way to do this is for you, in the SQL query, to specify which one. To do that , you would need to turn the SQL Into a `group by` SQL, and decide which one of the categories you want to list the name for.  And `Group by` queries are a whole other topic.

Comment: Okay, understood. I'll read up about group by and see if I can figure it out. Thanks for all your help Charles!