# Using GROUP By to display information from 3 tables

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've created a listing page where I have 3 tables

BND_Listing
BND_ListingCategories
BND_ListingJunction

The junction table contains ListingID & CategoryID to match which listings are in which categories.

I'm using the following select statement to pull data from these 3 tables into a grid on my website.

```
SELECT DISTINCT l.*, c.CategoryName 
FROM BND_Listing l
   Join BND_ListingJunction j
      on j.Junc_LID = l.LID
   join BND_ListingCategories c
      on c.CatId = j.Junc_CatID
Where (c.CategoryName = '[querystring:filter-Category]' or
                    '[querystring:filter-Category]'='All')
      and (City = '[querystring:filter-City]' or 
                    '[querystring:filter-City]'='All')
      and (Region= '[querystring:filter-State]' or 
                    '[querystring:filter-State]'='All')
      and (Country= '[querystring:filter-Country]' or 
                    '[querystring:filter-Country]'='All')
      and isnull(Company,'') <> ''
Order by l.Company, l.LID
```

The following query works fine but since I have some listings in multiple categories it's duplicating the listing for each category on my grid.

I'd like to show only uniquely 1 listing at a time even though they may be on more than 1 category.

I'm not sure how to accomplish this. I have another post explaining how I got this far. [Eliminate duplicates in Join over 3 Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40331037/eliminate-duplicates-in-join-over-3-tables)

Any examples, insight appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method would be to remove the category from the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT l.*
```

An alternative method would be to keep the category name for a singleton, and show `'Multiple'` for multiples:

```
SELECT l.company, l.LID, . . .,
       (CASE WHEN MIN(c.CategoryName) = MAX(c.CategoryName) THEN MIN(c.CategoryName)
             ELSE 'Multiple'
        END) as CategoryName
FROM . . .
GROUP BY l.company, l.LID, . . .;
```

This can easily be extended to showing two different categories, with `'More than 2'` for multiples.

A more painful method would be to concatenate the categories together.

Comment: when you say concatenate do you mean my data manually on the table? Or concatenate through TSQL? Displaying 1 record with concatenated categories seems like the option I'm looking for.

Comment: @AlexP . . . That is a pain, if you have more than two categories.